# De onde vem o adjetivo "rox"?

Tags: etimologia, português-brasileiro, origem, girias

Não é uma palavra muito comum, mas uma vez ou outra me deparo com alguém dizendo que algo é "rox", ou seja "da hora", "louco", "muito bom".
Me lembro que essa palavra era um pouco mais comum por volta de 2005, lá pelo começo da época do Orkut.

> Essa apresentação é muito rox!

> Achei esse jogo rox.

Teria alguma relação com "rocks" do inglês, que significa "arrasa", "arrebenta"?

Comment: *Rox* é bom, certo? Nunca ouvi isso cá por Portugal.

Comment: @Jacinto Sim, esqueci de colocar o significado, vou adicionar. Obrigado.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Gíria pouco conhecida e usada praticamente só por jovens e que, na minha opinião, ficaria ridícula se usada por um adulto para dirigir-se a outro adulto. Isso porque a chance de alguém com mais de trinta anos conhecer o significado é mínima.

> [**Definição de "rox"**](http://www.dicionarioinformal.com.br/rox/)
>
> Gíria utilizada para dizer que uma coisa é muito legal, e que agrada muito a alguém. Tem origem na expressão inglesa "rocks", que tem o mesmo significado.
> É uma palavra absolutamente informal e utilizada por jovens.

- "Esse jogo rox"
- "Meu time rox"
- "Nossa, isso é muito rox!"

Comment: Um detalhe é que em inglês é um verbo, e no português transformaram em um adjetivo.

Comment: @BrunoLopes  Em inglês "rock" é uma verbo, um substantivo, e até um adjetivo.  Pode significar entre outras coisas, um pedra preciosa, um diamante, cocaína, crack, e como adjetivo:  "pertaining to or characteristic of musical rock."